# Building QuickFIX on Arch-ARM

Tags: compiling, raspberry-pi, arch-arm

I am running Arch Linux ARM on my Raspberry Pi, and am trying to install [QuickFIX](http://quickfixengine.org).

I believe that I have correctly installed all of [the dependencies](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/dependencies.html) and have successfully built the software from source.

Unfortunately when I follow [the test scripts](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/testing.html), I get the following error:

```
[alarm@alarm-rpi3 test]$ ./runut.sh 1026
ut: no process found
at: no process found
<ut>
  <output>
C++/test/FieldConvertorsTestCase.cpp:114: error: Failure in integerConvertTo: Expected -2147483648 but was -00
FAILURE: 1 out of 191 tests failed (1 failures).
Test time: 13.43 seconds.
  </output>
</ut>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about resolving this issue? Has anyone had any success running QuickFIX on Arch Linux?

Comment: Can anyone offer any assistance here?